# How to run 3 loops for conditional formatting over multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, loops, formatting, worksheet

I'm trying to conditionally format 4 worksheets with varying ranges without using Select

I'm trying to clean up my very crazy beginner code and speed up the process, but the loops are not working. All of the empty cells in the ranges on Worksheets 2 & 3 should be filled with "T". The empty cells in ranges on Sheets 4 & 5 should be "p".
All of the cells with data on sheets 2-4 are formatted the same: bold font, center alignment, frame, conditionally replace text and font & font color depending on cell text.

```
Sub comfor()

Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For i = 2 To 3
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"),_ ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
                   If Text = "" Then
                   Value = "T"
                End If
            Next
         End With
      Next

    For i = 4 To 5
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"),_ ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
                 If Text = "Not Recorded" Then
                    Value = "p"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next
    For i = 2 To 5
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"),_ ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
               With cell
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                   .Font.Bold = True
               End With

               With cell
                   .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
                   .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
                   .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
                   .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
               End With

               With cell
                    If .Text = "Incomplete" Then
                       .Font.Color = vbRed
                       .Value = "T"
                       .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"

                    ElseIf .Text = "Not Applicable" Then
                        .Name = "Webdings"
                        .Value = "x"
                        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)

                    ElseIf .Text = "Complete" Then
                        .Font.Color = 5287936
                        .Value = "R"
                        .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"

                    ElseIf .Text = "Not Recorded" Then
                        .Font.Color = RGB(129, 222, 225)
                        .Value = "p"
                        .Font.Name = "Wingdings"

                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the code incorrectly. I hit submit before I corrected it.

Comment: What are `Text` and `Value`? As your code stands, those are just undeclared variables. That should be `If cell.Value = "" Then` and `cell.Value = "T"`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I changed "Text" and "Value" to "cell.Value", but the when I run the code, the empty cells on the sheets are not filled and it takes a crazy long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your loops with this instead - a loop does not act the same as a `With` statement - you still have to explicitly refer to `cell.Text/cell.Value` - UNLESS you want to embed a `With` statement **inside** your loop - which you absolutely could - but even then, that would need to be `.Text` and `.Value`.

```
For i = 2 To 3
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"), ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
                   If cell.Text = "" Then
                   cell.Value = "T"
                End If
            Next
         End With
      Next

    For i = 4 To 5
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"), ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
                 If cell.Text = "Not Recorded" Then
                    cell.Value = "p"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next
```

Comment: I replaced what I had with the above, but still nothing happens.

Comment: `ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells` is most likely the culprit - what range are you expecting this to return?

Comment: The range on each ws is different. The number of columns/ws will not change, but the rows may based on the number of days in the month. All ws have a header, so I set up all to start formatting at A6. I originally set this up to select each page, the range, then format, but I hoped for a cleaner, quicker way. Also the only column that is guaranteed not to have empty cells is the date column "A".

Comment: I used the macro recorder and Ctl + End to  get ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"), ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells.

Comment: I noticed that when I hover over "cell" the pop-up states "cell =" the value in A6 on Sheet 1! I don't want to format Sheet 1 and Next is not progressing to another Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I used Select Case and the ws Name instead of i and adding "For Each ws.. before each Select Case, it works and runs very quickly. Maybe not the most elegant, but effective.

```
Sub comfor()

Dim daily As Worksheet, mon As Worksheet, per As Worksheet, surf As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range


Set daily = Sheets("Daily")
Set per = Sheets("Personnel")
Set surf = Sheets("Testing")
Set mon = Sheets("Monthly")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Daily", "Monthly"
        For Each cell In ws.Range(("A6"),_ 
ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
                If cell.Text = "" Then
                   cell.Value = "T"
                    cell.Font.Color = vbRed
                   cell.Value = "T"
                   cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
                   End If
            Next
    End Select
 Next

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Personnel", "Testing"
    For Each cell In ws.Range(("A6"), ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
             If cell.Text = "" Then
                cell.Value = "p"
                    cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                    cell.Value = "p"
                    cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"
                    End If
        Next

    End Select
Next

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Daily", "Monthly", "Personnel", "Testing"
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("A6"),_ 
ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
           With cell
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           End With

            With cell
             .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
             .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
             .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
             .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
             .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
             .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
             End With

                If cell.Text = "Incomplete" Then
                   cell.Font.Color = vbRed
                   cell.Value = "T"
                   cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"

                ElseIf cell.Text = "Not Applicable" Then
                    cell.Name = "Webdings"
                    cell.Value = "x"
                    cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)

                ElseIf cell.Text = "Complete" Then
                     cell.Font.Color = 5287936
                     cell.Value = "R"
                     cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"

                End If

            Next
    End Select
 Next

End Sub
```